# Output of screen recording low fps?

Tags: python, screen-recording

I have this screen recorder but the output i notice low fps, like a lot of frame drops, how to solve? My monitor has even 120 hz so it's vero smooth, but in the output is like 60 hz not very smooth, if i increase the fps valure from 6 to 20 for example the video is too fast like x2 in speed, so how to solve? Thanks

```
import datetime
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
file_name = f"{time_stamp}.mp4"
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc("m","p","4","v")
captured_video = cv2.VideoWriter(file_name,fourcc,6.0,(1920,1080))
while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1920,1080))
    img_np = np.array(img)
    img_final = cv2.cvtColor(img_np,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow ("Secret Capture",img_final)
    captured_video.write(img_final)
    if cv2.waitKey(50) == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by too accelerated and fast. Do you want a different framerate?

Comment: Hi @pcamach2, i mean that if you run the code in the final output the video is like x2 in the speed, like the speed of the video is increased, and i notice frame drops when i hold and move a window for example, if i increase the fps valure is even more speeded up, i simply want a real time recording, if is possible :D

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. If you want the same fps as your display resolution, why not set the fps value in cv2.VideoWriter to 120?

Comment: i'm not at home so i can try later on today, but remember that even with 20 in cv2.VideoWriter is like x2 speed, so i assume that 120 is more more and more fast following this logic, or am i wrong?

Comment: If you capture at 120 fps and render at 120 fps, the result should be the same smoothness as your display. The only cause for a video to be faster than what it recorded is if you render at a higher framerate than you capture. There might be practical limitations of your capture framerate depending on how efficient the code is and the hardware that you use to run it, which may explain frames dropping while you move windows.

Comment: Later on i come home and i try, i will let you know :D

Comment: An other question, if i capture at 120 fps how to render? I read that you wrote render